# Oracle Apex 18 shuttle item show last selected values on right side

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have implemented Shuttle List Successfully Using Dynamic Action with Below Code

```
declare
    tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
begin
    tab := apex_util.string_to_table (:P14_NEW_1);
    for i in 1..tab.count loop
        insert into xxtest (COL1, COL2)
        values (:P14_NEW, tab(i));
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
```

Problem is that each the time user open the forms it don't show the last selected values to Right Hand Side, I didn't understand this logic how can i show selected items as saved In table to Right side when page loads

Answer (score 0):

You did the first part of job - stored selected values into a table.

The next step is to retrieve them back. In order to do that,

- navigate to shuttle item's **source** property
- set its type to "SQL Query (return colon separated values)
- SQL query should look like this:

  ```
  select listagg(col2, ':') within group (order by null)
  from xxtest
  where ... --> include condition, if there is any - I believe it should
  ```
- set "Used" property to "Always, replacing any existing value in session state

Run the page; shuttle item should now have populated right hand side.

As of the `where` clause: I don't know what is the purpose of doing what you're doing, but - if you don't distinguish rows stored into the `xxtest` table, all users will use the same recordset and overwrite each other's data. If `xxtest.col1` represents username (so that wouldn't be `:P14_NEW` but `:APP_USER` instead), you should use it in `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, consider doing that.

Comment: col1 is deptno ,, i am filtering shuttle item from select list of Dept Table and Storing Depno to col1 as :P14_NEW,,, According to your Suggestion i am now showing the depno in Right side of shuttle itme instead of deptname

Comment: I am Making Refresh the Shuttle item when Select List of Departments is changed and its not showing the selected values